# Is it a Mitzva Deorayta (Biblical Commandment) to serve in the IDF?

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, army-military-war, state-of-israel

בס"ד

What do the contemporary poskim say about the serving in the IDF? Do they consider it a Biblical commandment (*mitzva de'orayta*) if one chooses to serve?

I am obviously not talking about the controversial draft. But if a Jew by his own volition wanted to serve in the IDF does he fulfill a Mitzvah DeAroaita. I've heard certain mitzvot like Protecting the Land, or Pikuach Nefesh are cited, but I wanted to know if anyone has any sources from contemporary poskim.

Thanks

Comment: i saw a tshuva from r moshe once in choshen mishpat, he mentions that one needs the urim vtumim to go to war, for without it, it would be assur to put yourself b'makom sakana

Comment: @TropicanaYid But the urim vtumim weren't available for questions during the Second Temple. Were the Maccabees wrong for fighting the Greeks?

Comment: Rav Moshe addresses in the tshuva the Maccabees. right now i cant find it, but if you could and post it here that would be very helpful!

Comment: Related\Possible duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17286/can-one-join-an-army

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9102/halachic-considerations-for-women-in-the-idf

Comment: @Tropicana yid , Its Igros Moshe CM 2:78 ,see also OC 4:75 at end

Comment: @TropicanaYid see the Tzitz Eliezer here http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14509&st=&pgnum=15

Comment: I would also suggest one read his Hilchos Medina http://hebrewbooks.org/20825

Comment: @Shmuel How would that be a dupe? It specifically doesn't cover this case.

Comment: Torahmusings.com just published an article on this today, but many already exist (some positive views from Rav Schachter and Rav Zevin though for different reasons)

Comment: @Matt http://www.torahmusings.com/2014/06/israeli-army-new-halachic-paradigm/

Comment: Many things have some component which can be categorized as a _mitsvah_. However, that doesn't tell you whether that this is forbidden or permitted, a good idea, or a bad idea. Accordingly, this seems lkea pretty meaningless question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51458/discussion-on-question-by-armoose-is-it-a-mitzva-deorayta-biblical-commandment).

Answer (score 3):

Reb Shlomo Zalman Auerbach says IDF soldiers may risk their lives to recover the body of a slain comrade because if soldiers think that if they are killed their bodies will be left in the field this would cause a weakening of their combat moral which poses pikuach nephesh to klal yisrael.

From this it seems evident RSZA was of the opinion that the IDF are protecting klal yisrael from a situation of pikuach nephesh and subsequently one can deduce that fighting in the IDF is a mitzva de'oraisa of saving many lives.

RSZA also paskened it is permissible to give maaser money to the IDF because it is le'tzorech mitzva.

Comment: Hi pcoz. Adding citations to support the claims in this post would make it more usable for us. Thanks.